# Multiple messages.error Django

Tags: python, django

I would like to catch incorrect information using Django messages. I have one `message.error` that works properly, but when I add more potential messages, they won't work. Here is my code:

```
def order_approve(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Approved(request.POST or None)
        success = False
        if form.is_valid:    

            order = request.POST.get('order')
            department = request.POST.get('department')
            name = request.POST.get('name')
            notes = request.POST.get('notes')
            check = department
            if check == 'wrong': #I have a column that is '-----' for placeholding
                messages.error(request, 'Please select a valid department')
            else:
                if department == 'sales':
                    approved = PDFStat.objects.filter(quote_num=order).values_list('sales_approved', flat=True)
                    if approved == True:
                        messages.error(requet, order + ' has already been approved by Sales')
                    else:
                        PDFStat.objects.select_related().filter(quote_num=order).update(
                            sales_name = name, sales_approved = True,
                            sales_date=datetime.today())
                        HomeTable.objects.filter(quote_num=order).update(
                            last_app = 'Sales')
                        if notes != '':
                            object1 = PDFStat.objects.select_related().filter(quote_num=order)
                            for a in object1:
                                if a.sales_notes == None:
                                    PDFStat.objects.select_related().filter(quote_num=order).update(
                                        sales_notes = notes)
                                else:
                                    a.sales_notes = a.sales_notes + " " + notes
                                    a.save()
        messages.success(request, 'The quote has successfully been approved by ' + name + ' in ' + department)
        form = Approved()
        success = True
        return render(request, 'approved.html', {'form': form})

    else:
        form = Approved()
    return render(request, 'approved.html', {'form': form})
```

My first `messages.error` works fine but when it gets down to the `if approved == True` regardless if it's true or false (in my database) it will move to the else. What am I doing wrong? All the objects are grabbing correct data.

Thanks for you help!

Comment: That's a pretty big view. Django's philosophy is "Skinny views, fat models", meaning you should try to keep the business logic in the models and in this case I think you'd benefit from refactoring everything under that `else` clause into functions. Either way, your best bet is to stick a breakpoint in the top of the view and step through with [`pdb`](https://pymotw.com/2/pdb/) to see if you're actually hitting the spots you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
approved = PDFStat.objects.filter(quote_num=order).values_list('sales_approved', flat=True)
```

This will return a values queryset e.g. `[True,]`. Comparing it to `True` will always return False.

Perhaps you want something like:

```
pdf_stat = PDFStat.objects.get(quote_num=order)
approved = pdf_stat.sales_approved
```

Note you may need extra code to handle the case when there are no rows or multiple rows that match the `get()`.

Comment: I messed up, totally forgot the query part of it. Instead of using a second `get()` I just did `if approved[0]` which seemed to work. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you got it working. I recommend you change the code so that `approved` really is `True` or `False`, rather than using `if approved[0]`. If having `approved = [True]` confused you today, then it can confuse somebody else (or even you) in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
 messages.error(requet, order + ' has already been approved by Sales').
```

`'requet' should be 'request'`.

String concatenate should be.

```
messages.error(request, '{0} has already been approved by Sales'.format(order)).
```